# Combinatorial problems in electronics

Tags: ds.algorithms, combinatorics, binary-decision-diagrams

This could be a downvoted question but I am asking because I am not able to get usable info via Google.

Are there any interesting combinatorial problems in the field of electronics circuits design? I am interested in solved problems and not in the high science.

I am asking this because we are looking for a diploma themas on Electrical Engineering faculty. We will try to guide and help our students (I am a part of staff) to solve these problems using a BDD package in a similar way as BDDs are used to solve 8-Queens problem and other combinatorial problems found in Knuth's book and various research papers.

We have Quine-McCluskey minimization, but are there also some more hardware-related problems?

Comment: From Minato: "Zero-Suppressed BDDs and Their Applications", 2001, we have Fault Simulation, Multi-Level Logic Synthesis, PLAs, Prime-Irredundant Cube Sets, and Factorization of Cube Sets. We are still interested in any new proposal.